# Install HP 5740 office-jet all-in-one on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, usb, hp, scanner, hplip

I updated from ubuntu 14 to 15.04 so HPLIP 3.15.2 is installed and in theory the HP printer officejet 5740 e-all-in-one should be supported. Yet the HPLIP does not recognize the printer from the USB connection (although the lsusb command from terminal shows that a printer is indeed connected: Bus 002 Device 004: ID 03f0:cd11 Hewlett-Packard.

I can actually print using the installation from the system setting, but I don't have the scanner and let alone the fax. Neither of 'Simple scan', 'Acquire Images' and 'Xsane' identify a scanner. The CUPS web interface shows that there is a printer named 'HP_Officejet_5740_series', with description 'HP Officejet 5740 series' and 'Driver: HP Officejet 5740 Series, hpcups 3.15.2 '; connection 'usb://HP/Officejet%205740%20series?serial=TH4A6330Q805ZF&interface=1'; location 'Gigiux'. I can even print the test page. Yet the HP Device Manager does not identify a printer neither from USB (thus the wireless connections are also non available) nor from CUPS. Hence no scanner (let alone the fax). Even providing the direction of the usb (002:004) does not help.

So the question is: how can I properly install the HP officejet 5740 e-all-in -one and specifically how can I set the scanner (and optionally even the fax)?

Thank you

Gigiux

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I download and install the newer Hplip driver from this page
http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/officejet/officejet_5740_series.html

Everything works for me (I do not test fax) with a wireless connection.

hplip version is 3.15.7 and
XSanne recognize the scanner immediately

Fred